# Loading an Array into a list, but it's duplicating with new memory (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to load an array, that I've read in from a text file, to be displayed as a `JList`. This is the method I have for loading the elements from the array into the `JList`

```java
private JList stockList;
private JButton LoadStock;
DefaultListModel<String> model;
stockDataManager stockdataManager = new stockDataManager();
ArrayList<stock> shopStock = stockdataManager.getShopStock();

public void UpdateJList() {
    stockdataManager.load();
    model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    model.clear();
    for (stock p : shopStock) {
        model.addElement(p.toString());
    }
    stockList.setModel(model);
    stockList.setSelectedIndex(1);
}
```

The `ArrayList` is referenced from another class.

```java
private final ArrayList<stock> shopStock = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<stock> getShopStock(){
    return shopStock;
}
```

However every time I click the load button to load in my stock onto the `JList`, it will duplicate it, due to the fact I'm having an add and edit function. This means whenever I add new stock onto the array and try to update it, it's pasting in all the elements again but with new memory tags. Another issue I'm having is that it displays the array elements as their memory tags and not their string format.

I have not been using Java for very long and I'm pretty new to it so sorry if it's scuffed.

Comment: Try overriding the toString() method of the Stock class, as that might be printing the complex object not the expected value.

Comment: Thanks Prateek, that's sorted one of my problems!

Comment: Can you explain to me the other problem? It wasn't clean enough for me.

Comment: I think shopStock object is having the old objects also, resulting in duplicates. Can you debug and check that?

Comment: @PrateekPande I have a class which reads in data from a txt file, that data is the stored in array shopStock, the UpdateJList Function is loading the data from that array and then adding all the elements from that array as a string into my Listbox using a default list model, however because in my app you can add new stock items into that array everytime i re-load it it's just duplicating that array and displaying it in the list box, i thought added model.clear before it re-adds it onto the list box would work but it doesn't? Hopefully this makes a bit more sense

Comment: Are you deleting the data from the file also, or only the list? And while writing to the file are you writing the complete list back, or how do you track the modified data in the list?
I suspect that could be the problem.